# Chrome Extensions API future releases

Tags: google-chrome-extension

could someone help me with finding a place (URL, RSS feed or something else) where I could find what changes will be done in chrome extension API in each new Chrome release. It will be very useful to have that information before release to prepare extension.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the 'source of true' for Chrome extensions (APIs and other important topics around it) - http://blog.chromium.org/search/label/extensions